# SQL Server 2005 version comparison / differences

Tags: sql-server-2005, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

SQL Server isn't really my strongpoint but at the moment I've got to spec a new server on the Dell website and I was confronted with the following options:

Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2005 Workgroup Edition with 5 Client Licenses - English [add **£510.00**]
Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2005 Workgroup Edition, Single Processor License - English [add **£2,730.00** or £149/month-1]
Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2005 Workgroup Edition, Dual Processor License - English [add **£5,500.00** or £251/month-1]

I understand why the dual processor licence is more expensive than the single processor, but what is the difference between the 'Workgroup Edition with 5 CALs' and the 'Workgroup Edition, Single Processor Licence', ie why is the latter more than 5 times the cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Client Access Licences you need one licence for each client that connects. A processor licence alows unlimited clients connecting to SQL running on that processor. That's why it's expensive! NB One processor <> one core. Once processor means e.g. one Core 2 Quad. These days I favour buying single quad cores over twin dual cores for just this reason.

JR

Answer (score 1):

John is correct - [This link at Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/licensing.aspx) goes into the details.